# What is the difference between `chmod go-rwx` and `chmod 700`

Tags: unix, filesystems, chmod

My goal is to prevent `modify/read` permission of other users except the owner. [On ubuntu forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1387058) as solutions both approach is given.

> ```
> sudo useradd -d /home/newuser -m newuser
> chmod 700 /home/newuser # or # chmod go-rwx /home/newuser
> ```

**[Q]** Is there any difference between `chmod go-rwx` and `chmod 700` or both accomplish the same thing? If there is a difference which one is recommended?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: Sure I can ask on Ubuntu. But shouldn't be general for Linux ? @Andrew Morton

Comment: this is most definitely not Ubuntu specific, as I have done this years before Ubuntu was dreamed of...

Comment: @alper Either way, it's off-topic on Stack Overflow. You mentioned Ubuntu in the question, so I took the effort to get the link for an Ubuntu-specific SO site instead of clicking on the "belongs on Super User" option.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`go-rwx` removes **r**ead, **w**rite, e**x**ecute permissions from the **g**roup and **o**ther users. It will *not* change permissions for the **u**ser that owns the file.

Therefore e.g. a file with 644 (`rw-r--r--`) permissions will have 600 (`rw------`) after the command.

`chmod 700` on the other hand will always change the permissions to 700 (`rwx------`), no matter the previous permissions.

So it depends on what you want to accomplish.

Notes:

- Especially when using `-R` to change entire directories, this makes `go-rwx` more useful, as the e**x**ecutable flag is usually only wanted on folders (so they can be entered) and program files that need to be executed.
  Using `700` would add the e**x**ecutable flag to *all* files that don't have it yet, which is usually not what you'd want to do.
- What the general effect of `chmod 700` would actually look like in the other notation is `chmod u+rwx,go-rwx` or `chmod u=rwx,go=` (grants all permissions to **u**ser that owns file, removes all permissions of **g**roup and **o**ther)
- Not all versions of chmod support the `ugo±rwx` syntax scheme.

Answer (score 8):

There could be a difference:
`chmod 700` lets the owner read , write  and execute, and gives no permissions for Group and Other.

`chmod go-rwx` removes read/write/execute permissions from group and others, but preserves whatever permissions the owner had.

So, for example, if the owner didn't have execute permission on the file, to begin with, and only had read and write, the result could be different. With `chmod 700`, the owner would also get execute permission, which he would not with `chmod go-rwx`.

Comment: I want to give execute permission on the file for the owner. So `chmod 700` seems like a better option? @Gonen I

Comment: It will only be different if the owner didn't already have r/w/x permissions. If it's OK for the owner to have all 3 , you can safely use chmod 700